# Analyze CodeCompileUnit for used types / classes

Tags: c#, razor, codedom

I am building a Razor template-parser using something like the following:

```
RazorEngineHost host = new RazorEngineHost(new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
RazorTemplateEngine engine = new RazorTemplateEngine(host);
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

GeneratorResults razorTemplate = engine.GenerateCode(new StringReader(template));

var cParams = new CompilerParameters();
// set params....

var result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(cParams, razorTemplate.GeneratedCode);
```

Now I would like to analyze `razorTemplate.GeneratedCode` for the usage of some classes for security reasons, e.g. when/before compiling the following:

```
@{ System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => while(true)); }
```

I would like to detect the usage of `Task` and then not compile it and throw a security-exception.
Because this are Razor-templates the following should be valid:

> <i>System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => while(true))</i> is evil. Render-time: @DateTime.Now

so I can not use "simple text-search" to validate the templates.

*How can I do that?*

I already searched the `razorTemplate`-object via the debugger, but I did not find "any methods" in there...

P.S.: The complete code can be found [HERE](https://isolatedrazor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/IsolatedRazor/RazorTemplater.cs) in the method `CompileAsync`.

Comment: It is not impossible, you can use Reflection to analyze the code.  It is however a project that only ever gets started, never finished.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am aware, that it will never be "perfect", but at least some level of security would be nice (i.e. detect any usage of `Task` or `Thread`). Can you give me a starting point how this could be done? I searched a lot and only found "the other way around", but no example on how to analyze already created "code"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example template, when you look at the statement that corresponds to the `Task`-using code (it's something like `((CodeMemberMethod)razorTemplate​.GeneratedCode​.Namespaces[0]​.Types[0]​.Members[1])​.Statements[0]`), you'll see that it's a [`CodeSnippetStatement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetstatement). That means that CodeDOM doesn't know anything about the structure of the statement, it's just a string.

So, if you're not willing to try to parse the code yourself (possibly using some existing compiler, like Roslyn), you can't get the information you want from CodeDOM.

Another option would be to use the compiled assembly. In it, in the `TypeRef` table, are stored all types that are used in the assembly. This table is not accessible through normal reflection, but metadata reader like Mono Cecil can read it for you.

Comment: `in the TypeRef table, are stored all types that are used in the assembly` - thats exactly what I need. I checked it with `ILDASM`, but I havn't found any example or documentation how to use `Mono.Cecil` to read the `TypeRef` table (only `TypeDef`). Do you know any example for that?

Comment: I posted this as a follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588882/read-get-typeref-table-from-assembly-metadata