# Read/Get TypeRef table from assembly metadata

Tags: c#, reflection, metadata, clr, mono.cecil

This is a follow-up question to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562708/analyze-codecompileunit-for-used-types-classes) one:

To analyze an assembly (or the types it ueses) I would like to read the `TypeRef` table of such assembly.

I got the hint to use `Mono.Cecil` to do this, but I only found examples reading `TypeDef` information. Also browsing the source-code of cecil I only found internal classes which seems to me are responsible for reading the metadata, but I found no "public interface".

I also found [THIS](http://iobservable.net/blog/2013/05/12/introduction-to-clr-metadata/) article which uses some COM-library to read metadata, but I couldn't figure out how to use that for my purpose either.

**Can anyone tell me how I can read the `TypeRef` table (preferable using somthing like `Mono.Cecil` and not COM) of an assembly?**

I am also happy if someone can point me in the right direction...

Comment: Why is using `Mono.Cecil` _preferable_ if it can be achieved otherwise, even potentially without a third party?

Comment: @GrantThomas: Thanks for the hint: I meant "preferable without COM" - I edited the question to make it clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cecil, it's just a matter of accessing `ModuleDefinition.GetTypeReferences()`. For example:

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);

var typeReferences = assembly.MainModule.GetTypeReferences();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I don't know how often I look over the methods of `MainModule`, but I just did not see that one (maybe becuase I was looking for a `TypeRefs`-property)...